# Who command: what is S on slackware?

Tags: who

```
 who -r
         run-level 4  2015-01-19 21:56                   last=S
```

I'm on slackware,what does it mean S?
Previous runlevel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup.  Previous runlevel, which in this case appears to be **S**ingleuser mode.